# Unable to run Chromium/puppeteer on Heroku due to sanbox issues

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer

This is how I am launching `pupetteer` in `node.js`

```
const page = await puppeteer
    .launch({
      headless: true,
      slowMo: false,
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
    })
    .then(browser => browser.newPage());
```

But I still get the below errors

```
2018-11-27T05:21:26.673256+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:65) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
2018-11-27T05:21:26.673272+00:00 app[web.1]: [1127/052125.922709:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(116)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.
2018-11-27T05:21:26.673275+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 0x55939710acac base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Debian 8.11, node 11.11.0 - did you find a solution to this one?